# How can I get the parameter of a method in C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a game in Unity and suddenly this problem appeared.
Is it possible to get the parameter of a method in C#?

for example:

```
void Print1(string message)
{
    print("message");
}

void Print2(string message)
{
    //PseudoCode
    message = Print1message;
    print("message")
}
```

So, let's say that the method Print1 has been called and then, we want that the method Print2 get that same value.
For example:

Print1 receives the parameter "Hello World" and if we call Print2, we should get the parameter "Hello World" of Print1 and show it.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use global variable like this :

```
string GlobalMessage;

void Print1(string message)
{
GlobalMessage=message;
print("message");
}

void Print2(string message)
{

message = GlobalMessage;
print("message")
}`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
string Print1(string message)
{
    print(message);
    return message;
}

void Print2(string message)
{
    var msg = Print1(message);
    print(msg);
}
```

Comment: why would you return the same input you give to the function?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, but seemed like that's what OP was asking.

Comment: I think he was looking for something like @fkr.ayoub answer, even though it would not make that much sense either.